# Compiling python source to executable on windows fails

Tags: python, pandas, compilation

I am trying to compile python code on Windows and while running the compilation script I get a lot of warnings. The compilation itself is successful but the executable doesn't work anyway and crashes without giving an error. So, I guess it's missing libs mentioned in the warning message:
https://ibb.co/PxXkrxY

It's many lines but basicaly the same libs allover.

I have googled this issue and found many answers that say I just need to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 and I did that multiple times (uninstall, repair, different versions ...) and the issue persists. 
I droped the venv multiple times and did all the setup again after installing the new C++ stuff .. and the issue persists.
I checked the path, python is setuped correctly. So, I have no idea what else to try.
This is from my apps on Windows 10, the Visual stuff i have installed: https://ibb.co/x72ftnd

This is 64bit Windows 10 (but the issue exists also on Win7). 
Python 3.7.3

for compiling I use: PyInstaller==3.3.1

And this is the requirements file:

```
altgraph==0.15
appJar==0.93.0
future==0.16.0
macholib==1.9
numpy==1.14.5
pandas==0.24
pefile==2017.11.5
PyInstaller==3.3.1
pyodbc==4.0.24
pypiwin32==223
python-dateutil==2.7.3
pytz==2018.5
pywin32==223
six==1.11.0
```